# css div within div square alignment issue

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to create a square of 6 * 6 input box in a html page. In order to position them, I use divs and css:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box_0_0"><input... ></div>
    <div class="box_0_1"><input... ></div>
    <div class="box_0_2"><input... ></div>
    <div class="box_0_3"><input... ></div>
    ...
    <div class="box_1_0"><input... ></div>
    <div class="box_1_1"><input... ></div>
    ...
</div>
```

where

```
.boxes { position: relative; }

.box_0_0 { position: relative; float: left; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 40px; height: 50px; }
.box_0_1 { position: relative; float: left; top: 0px; left: 50px; width: 40px; height: 50px; }
...

.box_1_0 { position: relative; float: left; top: 60px; left: 0px; width: 40px; height: 50px; }
.box_1_1 { position: relative; float: left; top: 60px; left: 50px; width: 40px; height: 50px; }
```

but the result is not a square alignment:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out `float: left` and use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` on `box_0_0` and the rest. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/KdRre/1/

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us how you want them to look? like a chess pad with all squares aligned to each side?

There is not point giving a relative position to an element inside a relative div - give the internal div's a position absolute if needed.

Although if you are trying to get the boxes next to each other - use an unordered list to contain each box - may be an unordered list for each line if you know the number of boxes to place in a each line.

Else a float left with relative position removed would also work.

Let me know in-case you face an issue - I shall surely see that you get a solution - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a layout like this:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="left_0 top_0 box"><input... ></div>
    <div class="left_1 top_0 box"><input... ></div>
    <div class="left_2 top_0 box"><input... ></div>
    <div class="left_3 top_0 box"><input... ></div>
    <div class="left_0 top_1 box"><input... ></div>
    <div class="left_1 top_1 box"><input... ></div>
    ...
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
.boxes { position: relative; }
.box   { position:absolute;width:40px;height:50px; }
.left_0 { margin-left:0px;}
.left_1 { margin-left:50px; }
...
.top_0 { margin-top:0px; }
.top_1 { margin-top:60px; }
```